# How to RegEx a string into a list?

Tags: regex, vb.net

How can I RegEx this string into a list?

My String is like this:

```
google (2.0.3)                         - Python bindings to the Google search engine.
bits-google (1.12.17)                  - BITS Google
oauthkit-google (0.1.2)                - OAuthKit for Google
google-reauth (0.1.0)                  - Google Reauth Library
google-common (0.0.1)                  - Google namespace package
google-colab (1.0.0)                   - Google Colaboratory tools
google-auth (1.11.2)                   - Google Authentication Library
  INSTALLED: 1.7.0
  LATEST:    1.11.2
google-endpoints (4.8.0)               - Google Cloud Endpoints
google-oauth (1.0.1)                   - OAuth2 for Google APIs
google-gax (0.16.0)                    - Google API Extensions
google-finance (0.1.0)                 - Google Finance API ikmgitj oijhotrjtrhj
                                         kjhghjihotrhjtri9h
```

I want to get the `name`, the `version`, the `description`, and eventually if its installed.

I know how to separate a string with only one space, but how do I do that when the string has multiple spaces which vary and also have a dash in it?

**EDIT:**

I integrated the code now like this (For the people who are interested. [Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60362707/how-to-regex-a-string-into-a-list#answer-60367336)):

```
 Dim patt = "(.*?.)(\(\d+.\d+.\d+\)|\d+.\d+.\d+)(=?.*?-.)?(.*)"
        Dim matches = Regex.Matches(sOutput, patt, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        Dim found_packages As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))

        For Each m As Match In matches
            Dim key = m.Groups(1).Value.Trim({" "c, ":"c})
            If key = "INSTALLED" Then
                found_packages(found_packages.Last().Key).Add(m.Groups(2).Value.Trim({" "c, ":"c}))
                Continue For
            ElseIf key = "LATEST" Then
                Continue For
            End If

            found_packages.Add(key, New List(Of String))
            found_packages(key).Add(m.Groups(2).Value.Trim({" "c, ":"c}).Replace("(", "").Replace(")", ""))
            If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(m.Groups(4).Value) Then
                found_packages(key).Add(m.Groups(4).Value.Trim({" "c, ":"c}))
            End If
        Next

        For Each package In found_packages
            Dim item As New ListViewItem
            item.Text = package.Key
            item.SubItems.Add(package.Value(0))
            item.SubItems.Add(package.Value(1))
            If package.Value.Count > 2 Then
                item.SubItems.Add(package.Value(2))
            End If


            lvPackages.Items.Add(item)
        Next
```

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: I am using vb.net. I know its not very professional but it's just for a small project

Comment: I tried the code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RegEx` to parse this input and create a `Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))` where each key-value entry is a property (the `name`) with several values (the `version` and the `description`):

```vb
Dim patt = "(.*?.)(\(\d+.\d+.\d+\)|\d+.\d+.\d+)(=?.*?-.)?(.*)"
Dim matches = Regex.Matches(txtIn.Text, patt)
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))

For Each m As Match In matches
    Dim key = m.Groups(1).Value.Trim({" "c, ":"c})

    dict.Add(key, New List(Of String))
    dict(key).Add(m.Groups(2).Value.Trim({" "c, ":"c}))
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(m.Groups(4).Value) Then
        dict(key).Add(m.Groups(4).Value.Trim({" "c, ":"c}))
    End If
Next
```

The `dict` contains the following:

```
google
     (2.0.3)
     Python bindings to the Google search engine.
bits-google
     (1.12.17)
     BITS Google
oauthkit-google
     (0.1.2)
     OAuthKit for Google
google-reauth
     (0.1.0)
     Google Reauth Library
google-common
     (0.0.1)
     Google namespace package
google-colab
     (1.0.0)
     Google Colaboratory tools
google-auth
     (1.11.2)
     Google Authentication Library
INSTALLED
     1.7.0
LATEST
     1.11.2
google-endpoints
     (4.8.0)
     Google Cloud Endpoints
google-oauth
     (1.0.1)
     OAuth2 for Google APIs
google-gax
     (0.16.0)
     Google API Extensions
google-finance
     (0.1.0)
     Google Finance API ikmgitj oijhotrjtrhj kjhghjihotrhjtri9h
```

You can get the values (`version` and `description`) of the `google` key (`name`) for example as follows:

```vb
Dim version = dict("google")(0)
Dim descrip = dict("google")(1)
```

Note that, both `INSTALLED` and `LATEST` keys have no `description` value, so the `Dim descrip = dict("LATEST")(1)` will throw an exception. So you have to check first. Now you have the `dict` dictionary where the `dict.Keys` are the `name-s` and the `dict.Values` are the `version-s` and `description-s` for each key.

If you just want to create a `List(Of String)`:

```vb
Dim patt = "(.*?.)(\(\d+.\d+.\d+\)|\d+.\d+.\d+)(=?.*?-.)?(.*)"
Dim matches = Regex.Matches(txtIn.Text, patt)
Dim lst As New List(Of String)

For Each m As Match In matches
    lst.Add(m.Groups(1).Value.Trim({" "c, ":"c}))
    lst.Add(m.Groups(2).Value.Trim({" "c, ":"c}))
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(m.Groups(4).Value) Then
        lst.Add(m.Groups(4).Value.Trim({" "c, ":"c}))
    End If
Next
```

Here's the [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Ou5ruY/15) test for the preceding RegEx pattern.

---

**Edit: Suggested Improvements**

According to your last edit which clarifies what you are trying to achieve, I'd like to suggest the following:

- You can get rid of the `Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))` and work directly with the `ListViewItemCollection` of the `ListView` control. This way, just one `ForEach` loop will do the job.

```vb
Dim patt = "(.*?.)(\(\d+.\d+.\d+\)|\d+.\d+.\d+)(=?.*?-.)?(.*)"
Dim matches = Regex.Matches(sOutput.Text, patt)

lvPackages.BeginUpdate()
lvPackages.Items.Clear()

For Each m As Match In matches
    Dim key = m.Groups(1).Value.Trim({" "c, ":"c})

    If key.IndexOf("latest", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 Then
        Continue For
    End If

    Dim lvi As ListViewItem

    If key.IndexOf("installed", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 Then
        lvi = lvPackages.Items.OfType(Of ListViewItem).LastOrDefault
        'Just in case
        If lvi IsNot Nothing Then
            lvi.SubItems.Add(m.Groups(2).Value.Trim({" "c, ":"c}))
        End If
        Continue For
    End If

    lvi = New ListViewItem(key)

    'Add the version..
    lvi.SubItems.Add(Regex.Match(m.Groups(2).Value, "\d+.\d+.\d+").Value)

    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(m.Groups(4).Value) Then
        'Add the description..
        lvi.SubItems.Add(m.Groups(4).Value.Trim({" "c, ":"c}))
    End If

    lvPackages.Items.Add(lvi)
Next

'Optional: Auto size each column to fit the longest item.
lvPackages.Columns.Cast(Of ColumnHeader).
    ToList().ForEach(Sub(x) x.Width = -1)

lvPackages.EndUpdate()
```

Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for regular expressions. You can parse the string using a variable number of whitespace characters. I'm not sure about vb, but in python I would do something like this (but iterating over each line by splitting based on the \r):

[image: python regex]

Comment: Seems nice, but what should I do when the line is installed or latest?

Comment: I would handle that irregularity by using a try/except statement or and if/else  So that when you get to a line that doesn't parse, you try parsing it a different way to catch those exceptions

Comment: I alos see taht when the name has a hyphen, the regex sees it as a new match. Im not good with Regex, so can you tell me how its done?